# Bash script produces different output when run and when run in comand line

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to find all files with a specific name and copy them in a folder.

```
find FOLDERTOSEARCH -iname SEARCHTAG -type f -exec cp '{}' FOLDERDESTINATION \;
```

When I run this command in my shell it copies two files.

I wanted then to make it a script so I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $3 
find $1 -iname $2 -type f -exec cp '{}' $3 \;
```

And then I called it from shell with:
findcopy.sh FOLDERTOSEARCH SEARCHTAG FOLDERDESTINATION

And here it just copies one file.

I am new to bash.

Comment: Probably unrelated but quote all the viarables: `mkdir "$3"`  and `find "$1" -iname "$2" -type f -exec cp '{}' "$3" \;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you alot, I tried to "debug" by writing echo instead of find.
It looks like it replaces recursive the variables or something.

Comment: Without quoting the variables, the shell may interpret some of the characters you have in the variables in ways you do not want. If `$1` contains `foo bar` for example, it would search the two folders `foo` and `bar`. With quotes around, it'll search the one folder `foo bar`.

Comment: That sounds exactly what I saw when i used echo. Thanks again.

Comment: Also quotes are your friend, try to put your vars in them, eg "$3"